# Angular.js passing scope properties as reference to directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I pass a controller scope as reference to my directive? I want to pass some values like

```
<mydirective id="data.User.id" name="data.User.name" />
```

to the directive and when its changed internally by the directive update it in the controller.

The scope for this in the controller would be:

```
    $scope.data= {
        User: {
            id: '1',
            name: 'foobar'
        }
    }
```

I know that I can use `scope: {...}` in the directive to link some scope properties like this

```
    scope: {
        id: '=',
        name: '=',
    },
```

but as far as I understood this, this will basically be "hard coded"? I mean that the changed data will be always made available as $scope.id and $scope.name in the controller. But I want to change the passed `data.User.id` in controller $scope.data.User.id.

I want to work with the data passed to the directive to update it in the parent controller. Any way to do this?

**Edit: There is obviously an issue with my explanation of what I want to get done, let my try to explain it better.**

I **don't** want to introduce a hard dependency between a specific scope property of the controllers scope. I'm basically looking for a solution to pass a specific data binding to the directive that I can modify inside it.

I **don't** want to do this:

```
scope: {
        data: "="
}
```

because it will make the directive dependent on the controllers $scope.data being present. Even more worse, it will make it dependent on `$scope.data.User.id` and name. **I want to make the directive reusable** with **any** two values I pass to the directive. The passed values should be updated inside the directive and the change reflected in the controllers scope. The two passed values (id, name) should be still bound (referenced) to the controllers $scope. So I want that `name` in the directive maps to `$scope.data.User.name` **without** hard coding that into the component.

Maybe my whole architecture of this is wrong, if so, how could I do it better?

Comment: why do you think this is hardcoded? I think 2-way binding with isolate scope is what you need in this case `scope:{id:"=",name:"="}`

Comment: By hard coded I mean it will rely on the property name being available in the controller. See my updated questions.

Comment: What if you read / update the scope within the directive's controller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind? I would have to specify the exact property of the controller $scope again then in the directive which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I had same conflict as you describe here. One option was to completely remove the scope:{data:"="} and do all editing / reading of scope data within the directive's controller. You can even set $scope.data inside, so the directive will be completely independent ( no nee to set $scope.data on the "outer" controller). By saying "directive's controller" I mean the controller that you can use as part of the directive, inside of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the whole "data" object, something like:

```
<mydirective id="data.User.id" name="data" />
```

and then:

```
scope: {
        data: "="
},
```

You will then be able to access all data inside isolated scope's "data".

You can also remove the isolated scope from the directive and just access it within the directive's controller / link function.
Hope it answers your question...

Comment: Well, but this is exactly causing the problem I want to resolve. I *don't* want to rely on data being set in the controller! The idea is to keep the directive flexible and to not make it dependent on a specific scope value being present.

Comment: OK - I understand. You can do the binding to $scope inside the directive's controller (is this what you where looking for?). On the other hand, there is an advantage of using isolated scope + setting the data for the directive on the external controller, because that way you can reuse this directive in other places with different data from different controllers